# Number of ways of painting n colors on r identical boxes, each box gets one color.

Tags: combinatorics

This seems like such a simple problem. But I have been trying to solve it for hours and the best I've come up with is a recurrence relation. Suppose we have n colors numbered 0,.., (n-1) and r identical boxes. We need to assign a color to each box. A color can be repeated. If the boxes were not identical, the answer would be $n^r$. For example, with n=3 and r=2 the answer is 6. The combinations are - 
(0,0); (0,1); (0,2); (1,1); (1,2); (2,2).

Comment: Stars and bars.

Comment: Why would that work here?

Comment: Because the boxes are identical, the important thing is how many have the first color, which is the number up to the first divider, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) there will be

$$\binom{n+r-1}{n-1}$$

such arrangements.

In the case of $n=3$ and $r=2$ that is $\binom{4}{2}=6$